# Error "Failed to install HelloAndroid.apk on device 'emulator-5554!"

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to run simple Hello World but it gives this error..

> Failed to install HelloAndroid.apk on device 'emulator-5554!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another emulator in AVD Manager and try to run your application in the new emulator. Hope this might help you

Answer (score 1):

Your Device may not have enough memory to install this .apk file. Your should Uninstall unnecessary application from settings > Manage Application > Click Uninstall onClicking Useless application and also clear data of that app.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close the project & eclipse.
2. Relaunch the AVD serperately, wait for it load completely. Unlock the screen.
3. Then clean your project and run it manually by selecting the emulator. (Change it to manual in the Run configurations).

Answer (score 0):

When it shows the red writing - the error , don't close the emulator - leave it as is and run the application again.